# How do I receive an xml response using php curl?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl

How do I receive an xml response using php curl?     I don't need to manipulate the xml or store it or anything like that.  I just need to receive it as plain xml.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/path/to/service'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
```

$store contains response.

Comment: In initial question you asked, "How do I receive an xml response". To receive response, you have to do request first. This is an URL of web service you sending request to.

Comment: Perfect.  That's the answer I needed.  You're so good.  Mind helping me out with a little project?  Shouldn't take more than 30 minutes for a guy of your caliber.  I'll be on ICQ we can talk there.